# SQL Server. What's faster for 1 row: Deleting and Inserting or Updating?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, triggers, sql-update

I have a table made out of 280 columns (bad implementation and can't be changed) and I have a trigger after update that deletes if exists and then inserts (which basically means update).

Is this faster than just updating?

We need to consider that the number of the columns and their order might change in the future.

Which way is faster? Is the faster way the best way? Or are there other things we need to take into consideration to consider a way "the best"?

Comment: You can test it.  But in general, I would expect one change to the data to be -- oh, say -- twice as fast as two changes.

Comment: *"We need to consider that the number of the columns and their order might change in the future."* Seriously..? If the columns and the order of them change then you have a severe design flaw. Something is incredibly wrong. Add that to the 280  columns and yeah... Time to redesign the whole thing from the ground up.

Comment: @Larnu well, the database was initially made with Cobol in the 70's. It would be pretty nasty to make everything from the ground up

Comment: @GordonLinoff Not entirely true, updates can be complex enough that they are more than half an insert/delete. It can also depend on whether the clustered key changes, in which case it gets broken down to an insert/delete pair anyway. But you're obviously right that updates are nearly always faster

Comment: But we're not in the 70's any more @PedroEmilioVélez . We're in the 20's of the followong century. Yes, it is a bit task, but yes you clearly need it.

Comment: Cobol? When you tagged SQL server, you did mean the Microsoft SQL server? Just checking

Answer (score -3):

Delete + Insert is almost always faster because an Update has way more steps involved than simply just deleting or adding a new row.

- After further research I did find that SQL Server has two separate mechanisms for performing an UPDATE "in-place update (Will updated record at it's current place), and not-in-place update (Will delete and insert new record), considering this I would suggest using a normal Update and allow SQL Server figure out how to best update the record)

For more details check out Kalen Delaney, Paul Randal's, et al.'s book - SQL Server 2008 Internals.

Comment: Would you please give me the comparison between the steps involved in both queries?

Comment: If you're going to state this, some citations would be great.